# Issue on Changing The Flag Boolean State with and Operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/634s2wtm/1/) and let me know why I am not able to properly change the state of flag boolean (`var proceed = false;`) through

```
if (emailInput($('#email')) && emptyPass($('#password'))) {}
```

As you can see I am trying to check if the `emailInput()` **AND** `emptyPass()` return the `inputData` then change the Boolean to `true` but it seems the code is only functioning the `emailInput()` when both inputs are empty! (if user fills the email input then the password error message shows up, however)

```js
$(function () {
    var proceed = false;
    var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

    function emailInput(elem) {
        inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
        if (inputData == "") {
            elem.parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Field Can Not Be Empty</div>').slideDown("slow");
        } else if (!emailRegex.test(inputData)) {
            elem.parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Please Enter Valid Email Address</div>').slideDown();
        } else {
            return inputData;
        }
    }

    function emptyPass(elem) {
        inputData = $.trim(elem.val());
        if (inputData == "") {
            var $div = $('<div/>', {
                class: 'alert alert-danger err',
                role: 'alert'
            }).hide().text('No Empty');
            $div.insertAfter(elem.parent());
            $div.slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            return inputData;
        }
    }

    $("#login").on("click", function (e) {
        $(".err").hide();
        if (emailInput($('#email')) && emptyPass($('#password'))) {
            tempEmail = $('#email').val();
            tempPass = $('#password').val();
            proceed = true;
        }

        if (proceed) {
            var data = 'email=' + tempEmail + '&pass=' + tempPass;
            console.log(data);

        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");
body {
    padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="login-form" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group" id="emailBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            @
          </span>

            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group" id="passBox"> <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
            </i>
          </span>

            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Access</button>
            </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first, you need to declare your local variables (`proceed`, `inputData`) with `var`.  Second, you need to understand that the `&&` operator will only evaluate the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression succeeds. If the email address is empty or not valid, then the `&&` will just stop and the password field won't be tested at all.

You can ensure that both sides are tested like this:

```
  var proceed = true;
  if (!emailInput($('#email')))
    proceed = false;
  if (!emptyPass($('#password')))
    proceed = false;
```

After that, `proceed` will be `true` only if both the email address and the password are OK.

[Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/897ny81r/)